# Update table sqlite3

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am attempting to update an sql table in python to increase the value of an Americano coffee, but the sql statement

```
con = sqlite3.connect('Users.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE USERS SET AMERICANO = 2 WHERE ID = ?;", (self.Id))
```

Doesn't update the table and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit the changes. From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects)

> commit()
>
> This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not
>   visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t
>   see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t
>   forget to call this method.